# Ionic Project error of add platform

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I have to add iOS platform in ionic but I get permission error. (EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/macbookpro/.config/configstore/insight-cordova.json' You don't have access to this file.)
I have followed some steps regarding NPM but not got any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just try changing permissions of the file insight-cordova.json by below command:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 '/Users/macbookpro/.config/configstore/insight-cordova.json'
```

And this should fix the problem.

Comment: Could you please acept the answer if it solved your problem? thanks :)

Comment: By apply this I get error of like this Below.No such file or directory..

Comment: Find where the file regarding the error is located 'insight-cordova.json', and then do the sudo chmod -R 777...

Comment: Thanks Javier Ailes for help...I get another way to solve this problem and its work nice...

Comment: Sounds good :) It would be good if you update your question here in the post, so anyone who comes after us to this post, can find the solution..! or link it at least